# How to make UICollectionView Appear like the scrolling Instagram Stories Preview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Sorry for the novice question but after many hours I cannot grasp how to layout the collectionViewCells properly to appear like the instagram page with the story clips at the top.

Currently this is the best I have with a collectionView (not working) and a tableView (working): [image]

However there are several problems. First of all, notice that the top bar, which is the collectionView bar is not flush on the left with the tableView items below it.

My code for this is:

```
extension ChatTableViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "profileClipView", for: indexPath) as! ProfileClipViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = "text"
        cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: "temp_me")
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let side = self.collectionView.bounds.size.height - 16

        return CGSize(width: side - 10, height: side)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    }

}
```

Clearly this is spaced more than 8px, so my fundamental understanding of insets must be wrong. Also, I notice there is no way to set the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in the code, I assume it gets set when I set the collectionView delegate/datasource.

Another problem I am having is that the text below the photos never appears. I created a xib that appears as follows:

[image]

The imageView is 1:1 and clipped to the top and sides, the bottom black box is a lableView that is clipped to the image and bottom, and centered in the outer view. Notice that this label does not appear!

So ultimately I am wondering how to get the Cells flush with the sides, and wondering why the label does not appear. Appreciate help immensely!

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get the Cells flush with the sides"?

Comment: The label does not appear because the image view takes up all the space. I would put both of them is a vertical stack view and give a higher vertical hugging priority to your label.

Comment: Notice the top cells are not on the left side of the view.. I tried to have a inset of 8 from the left. Also, why would the imageVIew take up the entire space? I i do a stack then the label can cover the image.

Comment: Remove the imageview constraint bottom to give vertical spacing between the imageview and label.

Comment: Why is vertical spacing needed between them two?